# How to force Jest unit test assertion to execute before test ends?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs

I have the following test in my react native application, but the test should fail (because the action returned is not equal to the action I put in `expectedActions`. My guess is that it is passing because the `expect` test runs after the test has completed.

How can I force the test to wait until the promise is completed and the expect test runs? Is there another way of doing this?

```
describe('authorize actions', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        store = mockStore({});
    });

    it('should create an action to signify successful auth', () => {
        auth.authorize.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({"something": "value"}));
        const expectedActions = [{"type":"AUTHORIZE_RESPONSE","payload":{"something":"sdklfjsdf"}}];

        authorizeUser(store.dispatch, store.state).then(() => {
            expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
        });

    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like I just missed some of the Jest docs - if you return the promise, i.e. `return auth.authorize.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve...` then Jest will wait until it's completed before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

The are varios ways to test async code. Check the docs for examples: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html

One could be returning the promise:

```
describe('authorize actions', () => {
beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({});
});

it('should create an action to signify successful auth', () => {
    auth.authorize.mockImplementation(() => Promise.resolve({"something": "value"}));
    const expectedActions = [{"type":"AUTHORIZE_RESPONSE","payload":{"something":"sdklfjsdf"}}];

    return authorizeUser(store.dispatch, store.state).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
    });

})
```

});